# Can/should we use assert statement in a test class for batch processes?

Tags: unit-test, batch

I have a Batch process which updates a field on Account.
I have also written a test class for it. I have an assert statement to check if the field is getting updated.

Unfortunately this assert fails, this i would think is because the batch probably doesnt get executed immediately. Is there a way confirm that the batch is executed and only then do the asserts.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is to enclose the running of the batch file within startTest and StopTest methods

```
 System.Test.startTest();
   BatchClassName bc= new BatchClassName ();
    Database.executeBatch(bc, 200);
 System.Test.stopTest();
```